# Create Database Dynamically

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i am try to create database dynamically by VB.net by the following code

```
Dim str As String
Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=(local)\netsdk;" & _
                                     "uid=sa;pwd=a123;database=master")  

str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " & _
      "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " & _
      " FILENAME = 'E:\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " & _
      " SIZE = 2MB, " & _
      " MAXSIZE = 10MB, " & _
      " FILEGROWTH = 10%) " & _
      " LOG ON " & _
      "(NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " & _
      " FILENAME = 'E:\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " & _
      " SIZE = 1MB, " & _
      " MAXSIZE = 5MB, " & _
      " FILEGROWTH = 10%) "

Dim myCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, myConn)

Try
    myConn.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Database is created successfully", _
                    "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                     MessageBoxIcon.Information)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
Finally
    If (myConn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
        myConn.Close()
    End If
End Try
```

but I have the following error when the project run :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection     to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance  name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: should your con string be `(localdb)` instead of `(local)`?

Comment: the error still disply

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an actual server instance running that has the same name you're using in your connection string:

```
Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=(local)\netsdk;" & _
                                         "uid=sa;pwd=a123;database=master")
```

In this case, it's `(local)\netsdk`, and you apparently don't have an instance of SQL Server named `netsdk` installed on the machine where you're executing this code.

Comment: **You have to have a server instance with that name running on the computer**. I don't know how to be more specific. If you don't have a SQL Server instance named `(local)\netsdk` on the system, you can't create a database in it. If there's no woman named Mary, I can't refer to a male child as "Mary's son".

Comment: look i need way to create database by VB so after i purplish my Application run it App on computer without need SQL Server

Comment: You **cannot** create a SQL Server database on a computer that doesn't have SQL Server. It's called a **SQL Server database** because it needs **SQL Server** installed. Your connection string says there's a **Server** named `(local)\netsdk`, so that **Server** has to exist. You **cannot create a database on a server that does not exist**, no matter how badly you want to do so.

Comment: are found database without need to install server

Comment: Um. What? I have no idea what that means.

Comment: That's not the question you asked here. Google can answer that question. You asked what was causing the error, and I answered the question you asked.

Comment: BIG KEN, +1 this answer

Answer (score 1):

```
New SqlConnection("Server=(local)\netsdk;"
```

That says your app must connect to a SQL Server instance running on your machine.

> my Application run it App on computer without need SQL Server

That contradicts what your code says. It also contradicts the sql-server tag in your question. What kind of app are you building? A Windows desktop app? Winforms?

If you are building a single-machine app that must run without an installed database you should use an embedded database like [SQL Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx). The database runs inside your application and you do not need to run a separate instance.

The connection strings for SQL Compact are different from what you have shown, you will need to follow a tutorial. Click on "Learning Center" in the SQL Compact page.